# Is my logic wrong in writing this function? get_elements_that_equal_10_at_a_value

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

Write a function called `"get_elements_that_equal_10_at_a_value".`

Given a dictionary and a key, `"get_elements_that_equal_10_at_a_value"` returns a list containing all the elements of the list located at the given key that are equal to ten.

Notes:

- If the list is empty, it should return an empty list.
- If the list contains no elements that are equal to 10, it should return an empty list.
- If the value at the given key is not a list, it should return an empty list.
- If the key doesn't exist or its value is None, it should return an empty list.

```
obj1 = {'key': [1000, 10, 50, 10]}
output1 = get_elements_that_equal_10_at_a_value(obj1, 'key')
print(output1) # --> [10, 10]
```

```
obj2 = {'key': 10}
output2 = get_elements_that_equal_10_at_a_value(obj2, 'key')
print(output2) # --> []
```

My logic using the if-else approach:

```
def get_elements_that_equal_10_at_a_value(obj, key):
    new_d = obj.copy()
    lst = []

    if new_d[key] == [] or type(new_d[key]) == int:
        return []
    elif 10 in obj[key]:
        for x in obj[key]:
            if 10 == x:
                lst.append(x)
        return lst
    elif new_d.keys == None or new_d[key] == None:
        return []
    else:
        return []
```

Error

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_4 (test_methods.TestScript)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/test_methods.py", line 43, in test_4
    self.assertEqual(main.get_elements_that_equal_10_at_a_value(obj, 'key'),
  File "/usr/src/app/main.py", line 5, in get_elements_that_equal_10_at_a_value
    if new_d[key] == [] or type(new_d[key]) == int:
KeyError: 'key'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can greatly simply your code by considering just three cases.

You first simply check if the `key` is in the `obj`, returning an empty list if not.

Then, you check the type, and if its anything but a `list`, you return an empty list.

Finally, use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to extract the `10`s in the list and return them.

```
def get_elements_that_equal_10_at_a_value(obj, key):
    if key not in obj:
        return []
    value = obj[key]
    if type(value) != list:
        return []
    return [val for val in value if val == 10]

obj1 = {'key': [1000, 10, 50, 10]}
output1 = get_elements_that_equal_10_at_a_value(obj1, 'key')
print(output1) # --> [10, 10]

obj2 = {'key': 10}
output2 = get_elements_that_equal_10_at_a_value(obj2, 'key')
print(output2) # --> []
```

**Edit:** You could simplify this even further by making use of [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), setting `obj[key]` to be the empty list if the `key` does not exist. Thanks to @m-z for suggesting this.

```
def get_elements_that_equal_10_at_a_value(obj, key):
    value = obj.get(key, [])
    if type(value) != list:
        return []
    return [val for val in value if val == 10]
```

Comment: You are a life-saver! I also did another version, but it said key-error. Do you know why it operates wrong?

Comment: Your original code didn't handle the case of the key not occurring the dict, you would need: `if key not in new_d or new_d[key] == [] or type(new_d[key]) == int:`

Comment: you may want `value = obj.get(key, [])` btw

Comment: Amazing! It feels like a door opened in my brain! Thank you so much!

Comment: Great suggestion @m-z, added that as an alternative

Comment: using the word "value/val" to mean three different things in the same tiny function

Comment: @patrick Two different things, not three things - `value` as used by the OP for the name of the function corresponds to what the variable `value` is in the function. As for the elements of the list, `val` seemed like a simple, logical choice (I mean its a list comprehension, it doesn't need a fancy name, `v` would also be sufficient).